# i have installed the 'colorama module successfully', still the command prompt showing that 'no module named colorama'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, module, nft

I'm trying to run a code with my command prompt, it initially gives me some requirement of the modules and i installed all of those successfully. but when try to run the code with `python main.py` the 1st module need to be import for the code `colorama`, it appears, `no module named colorama`. the complete code is given below, I need help guys', as soon as possible, please.
My OS is window 10 and I'm using python310
the code is:
`

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\NFT1\Codes\NFTs_Upload_To_OpenSea_With_Metadata-main> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\NFT1\Codes\NFTs_Upload_To_OpenSea_With_Metadata-main\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from colorama import init, Fore, Style
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\NFT1\Codes\NFTs_Upload_To_OpenSea_With_Metadata-main> python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\NFT1\Codes\NFTs_Upload_To_OpenSea_With_Metadata-main\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from colorama import init, Fore, Style
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\NFT1\Codes\NFTs_Upload_To_OpenSea_With_Metadata-main> pip install colorama
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.4.6)
```

`
you can see above, when i ran the code, the error appears, then i check the colorama, and it is already installed. Plus I've already tried by uninstalling it first and then installing it again, still not worked for me.
Thanks

1. I have uninstalled the module and then re installed it again, not worked
2. I have upgraded the pip, sill not worked
3. these are more modules, need to be imported after colorama, and I'm afraid that the same problem may come again with those modules too

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install colorama`, you might be using another python version's pip installed on the computer.

Comment: At that time i'was trying on something, but i hadn't been able to sort the things out so, i had then skipped that project, Thanks ANYWAY Brother